# Search algorithm in Windows 8

Tags: windows, algorithm, search, windows-8

I find the search function in windows 8 quite effective, what is the algorithm or method it uses for searching through so many files/folders so quickly?

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer because I'm not sure exactly, but presumably it indexes the filesystem and maintains quick links to common search terms, like "Control Panel," and also recently created or used files.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval